# 'requirepass' in redis.conf not taking effect

Tags: docker, redis

I'm running Redis in a docker container (Alpine Linux).
I followed the manual to set a password in the file /etc/redis.conf

*requirepass Abcd-1234*

However, when I reboot Redis (docker restart redis_container) I'm still told no password is set. '*CONFIG GET requirepass*' yields "".

The strange thing is, other parameters in the config file, do take effect at container reboot.

I can set a password by '*CONFIG SET requirepass Abcd-1234*' but it won't last to next reboot.

Any suggestion how should I troubleshoot this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While starting Redis, show the path to the config file. E.g.

```
redis-server /etc/redis.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I think it should be my docker container setup, as I followed your instruction but couldn't start redis-server with designated config file. Guess I'll have to correct my container first, then it should bring things to work.